# Scrolling bug for fixed position div with top attribute on mobile devices

Tags: css, iphone, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

This is a weird bug where my div with fixed positioning and top attribute as x pixels thinks that the top of the viewport didn't change when chrome/safari auto expand the viewport on scrolling.

What is more weird is that the other fixed positioned elements which stick to top/bottom edges of the viewport move naturally and keep stuck to viewport edges when chrome/safari auto expand on scrolling.

Is my CSS to be blamed for some reason ?

View the video showing the bug on youtube [here](https://youtu.be/AMJKq3vfFkQ). https://youtu.be/AMJKq3vfFkQ

The website is live at babbly.com if you want to debug the CSS. I pasted a simplified CSS here.

```
.div-which-is-supposed-to-stick-to-yellow-bar {
    height: 59px;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    transition: left .4s;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
}

.parent-of-above-div {
    position: relative;
    height: 59px;
    width: 100px;
}

.parent-of-parent-div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

The red box is the guy.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The `.parent-of-parent-div` has fixed positioning with `bottom` as `0`. And that is causing the `.div-which-is-supposed-to-stick-to-yellow-bar` move along with the bottom bar when view port is expanded/condensed on scrolling. After the scrolling stops, the browser re-analyses the CSS and applies `top` to `.div-which-is-supposed-to-stick-to-yellow-bar` resulting in a visual glitch as seen in the video.

What I did is moved the `.div-which-is-supposed-to-stick-to-yellow-bar` out of `.parent-of-parent-div` and put it under another parent which is relatively positioned. This stopped the `.div-which-is-supposed-to-stick-to-yellow-bar` from dancing around there by stopping my problem.